# How can these Visual Studio .config files all get listed under each other?

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, configuration-files

I have these config files in my simple Visual Studio 2012 solution.

[image]

notice how the `Web.config` has the `Debug` and `Release` files *under* it?

How can i do the same for the `system.diagnostics.config` files?

(apologies - i'm not sure what the term is for those `Debug` and `Release` files that get hidden, thingy-ma-bob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of an option  to achieve that by the user interface but this is how it looks in the project file (*.csproj) for a WinForm:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
     <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

You can do the same for the config files (which are found in element `None`) and add a `DependentUpon` element for the config files that you want to 'connect'

See the reference on [Common MSBuild project Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb629388.aspx)

---

Edit by PK:

Inspired from above, this is what I did to get it working:

```
<None Include="system.diagnostics.Debug.config">
    <DependentUpon>system.diagnostics.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="system.diagnostics.Release.config">
    <DependentUpon>system.diagnostics.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

So those two files don't have any *build action* (which u can also set in the GUI) but I had to edit the file to set the `DependentUpon`.